# Looking for help using php variable date in html

Tags: php, html, date, datepicker

Hi im trying to use this date picker but i want it to allow user to only pick between two dates from php variables min is the earliest pickable date and max is the latest this is one variant of what i have tried but none have worked so far.

Any help is apreciated in advance

```
    <form>
  <label>
    Choose your preferred party date (required, April 1st to 20th):
    <input type="date" name="party" min="<?= echo date($minLanding)>" max="<?= echo date($maxLanding)>" required>
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </label>

  <p>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the shorthand echo syntax `<?=` *and* echo together. Use one or the other. Also note that the proper closing tag is `?>`. And you'll likely have to provide a date format, though I'm not sure which off the top of my head.

```
<?= date('Y-m-d', $minLanding) ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d', $minLanding) ?>
```

If your values are already formatted dates:

```
$Today = date('y:m:d')
$minLanding = Date('y:m:d', strtotime('+14 days'));
$maxLanding = Date('y:m:d', strtotime('+9 months'));
```

Then just:

```
<input type="date" min="<?= $minLanding ?>" max="<?= $maxLanding ?>">
```

But note I think you'll have to use `Y-m-d` as the format instead of `y:m:d`.

Comment: Still not working this is my php code if it help see thanks           
      $Today=date('y:m:d');
    $minLanding = Date('y:m:d', strtotime('+14 days'));
    echo $minLanding;                                                                                      $maxLanding = Date('y:m:d', strtotime('+9 months'));
    echo $maxLanding;

Comment: If `$minLanding` already contains the formatted date, them just echo that by itself. And I'm not sure if `y:m:d` format will work.

Comment: Im trying to make it so that the user can only pick a date from 14 days from today and up to 9 months from today how could i reformat the date for it to function? Thanks

Comment: Thanks my rep to low for my like of your reply to show :)